# When do I need use emitAll instead of emit in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Code A, I should use `emit( Result.Success(listEntityToModel(it)) )`, and in Code B, I should use  `emitAll(s)`.

When do I need use emitAll instead of emit in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
   override fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {     
         return mRecordDao.listRecord().transform  {       
            emit(Result.Loading) 
            emit( Result.Success(listEntityToModel(it)) )
         }
    }
```

**Code B**

```
override fun listRecord(): Flow<Result<List<MRecord>>> {
   return  flow {
      emit(Result.Loading)
      val s=mRecordDao.listRecord().map { Result.Success(listEntityToModel(it)) }
      emitAll(s)            
    }
}
```

Comment: The built-in `emitAll` has essentially no use cases.  Its signature is pretty clear, though -- it emits the contents of a `ReceiveChannel`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why do you say it has no use cases? It can be used to concatenate flows and individual items into a single flow as done in Code B above. There are two `emitAll()` functions--the one in the code above emits the contents of another Flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` is called on each element of a parent flow. If you want to re-emit that element, the only thing you can emit is that one element.

Your Code A is kind of pointless, because it emits a Loading state presumably because you want to show in the UI that something is loading, but it immediately emits data afterwards, so there will be no time to show that loading state. And since the lambda in `transform` is called on each element *after* it arrives, it is too late for a loading state to be useful.

In Code B, you are building a flow from scratch with the `flow` builder. `emitAll()` emits an entire flow instead of doing it one by one. `emitAll(s)` is the same as `s.collect { emit(it) }`.